# On Apple M1 with Rosetta, how to open entire Terminal / iTerm in x86_64 architecture?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, apple-silicon, rosetta

As a developer, I have experienced major issues with installing languages, libraries and development tools from the command-line as Apple M1 has migrated over to using arm64 instead of x86_64 architecture.

In order to bridge the gap before all libraries and tools change over to arm64, and to avoid library incompatibilities between architectures, in many cases it may be easier for  developers to just emulate x86_64 to perform their library installs.

Comment: Note that Mojave was the last version to support i386  - The intel arcitecture now supported is is x86_64

Comment: It might also be easier for Apple Silicon to use Macports which has supported that since it was released. Which languages and libraries are not ARM?

Comment: yeah `i386` is strange, more here for `arch` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12763379/740575, updated to be more clear it was for x86_64

Comment: hmm we had several m1s setup over the past quarter, found this was best solution as we use brew.  dual brew and pyenv abandonment is where i stopped to take another look

Comment: What does " dual brew and pyenv abandonment" mean?

Answer (score 36):

After installing Rosetta:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

It seems to be a good idea to run your entire Terminal in Rosetta:

- Go to Finder > Applications and find your Terminal (this can also be other terminal app, like iTerm in my case)
- Right-Click the App and Duplicate it and rename it "Terminal x86_64"
- Right-Click "Terminal x86_64" > Get Info > Enable Open using Rosetta
- Click to Open the Terminal, type `arch` to verify it says `x86_64` now.
- Right-Click the `Terminal x86_64` in your Dock and click "Keep in Dock" for future use.

It is important to install/update/deploy within the "Terminal x86_64" window now, your normal Terminal will be `arm64` and won't have the same libraries.  Consider full emulation as the easiest solution without a lot of workaround with flags and running multiple `brew` in parallel.  It just works.

Source: https://betterprogramming.pub/5-things-i-have-learned-when-using-the-m1-chip-macbook-air-a77f93c50381#5a64

Comment: Does anyone else find it odd that 'arch' returns "i386", yet that refers specifically to 32-bit Intel ISA, which hasn't run on macOS since Mojave? The industry has adopted "amd64" and "arm64" as the names of the two prevalent ISAs.

Comment: it should be `x86_64`, probably didn't refactoring from `i386`, probably didn't matter until they noticed the issues requiring `arm64` compiled binaries.  `amd64` appears to be a subset of `x86_64` ‍♂️

Comment: `amd64`, `x64`, and `x86_64` are interchangeable names. :)

Comment: @Rob_vH i see that now.  found something regarding your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12763379/740575

Comment: `uname -m # machine hardware name` -> `x86_64 `, `uname -p # machine processor architecture name` -> `i386 `, and `arch -x86_64 command .... # run command in x86_64 arch`. So, `Terminal-x86_64.app` would be better.

Comment: macOS 13 doesn’t let me duplicate my terminal anymore. Is there any solution for this yet?

Comment: @gernophil there is a way to set terminal to the version mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718666

Comment: Regarding macOS 13, in case this is of any use here's a solution I detailed in the Apple forums which isn't great but worked for me. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718722?answerId=740569022#740569022
TLDR use Automator to make an Application that does Run Shell Script with `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "arch -x86_64 zsh"
end tell'`

Comment: My MacOS Apple Silicon prints "i386" as well if I type "arch" on a terminal with Rosetta mode.

Comment: The automator script from @rsethc above is the only way I could get an i386 terminal open